# Google Analytics - Custom Dimensions not working in SPA

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I've struggled with this for a few weeks now and I'm tearing my hair out. I just can't get custom dimensions to report whatever I do.

Here is my code that's in the HEAD of index.html

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1', { 
        'send_page_view': false,
        'custom_map': {
            'dimension1': 'user_location_id',
            'dimension2': 'user_location_name',
            'dimension3': 'user_id'
        }
    });

</script>
```

The **'send_page_view': false** stops a pageview being sent when the server initially sends the page, all pageviews are handled by the JS code below when a route is navigated to (including on first load).

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1', {
    page_path:"/users/xxx",
    page_title:"User Profile",
    user_id:"xxxxx",
    user_location_id:36,
    user_location_name:"North East"
});
```

All pageviews are being tracked correctly. If I look in my Chrome Dev Tools Network tab and find the IMG call to /collect I can see all the parameters that are being sent and they do not include the custom dimensions.

These are the querystring parameters that are sent when the image is loaded (with some info redacted to xxx).

```
v: 1
_v: j67
a: xxx
t: pageview
_s: 9
dl: http://localhost/
dp: /users/xxx
ul: en-us
de: UTF-8
dt: User Profile
sd: 24-bit
sr: 1920x1200
vp: 1039x1094
je: 0
_u: iCCAAUAB~
jid: xxx
gjid: xxx
cid: xxx.xxx
uid: xxx
tid: UA-xxxxxxxxx-1
_gid: xxx.xxx
_r: 1
gtm: u4s
z: xxx
```

A couple of things to note:

1) The custom dimensions are set up in GA and scoped to the user.

2) I was previously sending just one call to set the config when the user logged in to set the custom dimension values, not on every pageview but was advised against this on the GC Community forums.

3) Interestingly, the value i send in the user_id dimension is actually being used as the uid in the values sent above, the other two are completely ignored and not sent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this  in the end by adding the custom_map stuff in every single call to 'config'. Messy, but I tried everything and it was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   gtag('event', 'page_view', {
       page_path:"/users/xxx",
       page_title:"User Profile",
       user_id:"xxxxx",
       user_location_id:36,
       user_location_name:"North East"
   });
```

instead of `gtag('config' ...` for sending your pageview hits